# KSH script list files/directories in another place

Tags: linux, ksh

I'm learning KSH at the momment and wondering....if you used the command:

ls .* it would display all files in that current directory including any other directories.

what if I wanted to display all the items in another directory? How would I accomplish this.

This is what I used firstly:

```
#!/bin/ksh

echo "Files in Folder:"
ls .*
```

Comment: Read [Globs vs Regular Expressions](http://lwn.net/Articles/96687/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `ls .*` will only list the hidden files and directories which by convention start with a dot.  This will include `..`, which will actually be listing the files in the parent directory.  You can just use `ls` or `ls *`.  If you want to list the contents of another directory, use `ls $1` and call the script like so: `script.ksh /tmp`